# Always get 401 log in required from Gmail API

Tags: android, google-plus, gmail-api

OK, I had this working at one point, but then wanted to add a silent login (optional) at app startup. I now going crazy and am getting following error

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header",
      "message": "Login Required",
      "reason": "required"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Login Required"
}

This occurs on the line (should I be using "me"?)

```
Message messageResult = mGmailService.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();
```

whenever I try to send (in the case above) or read email (not shown). Ultimately, all I want to do with the app is to read user emails and send on their behalf. The app is registered, has the keys, permissions, etc.

I am setting up the data as (you can see my various comments as I tried to things working):

```
    mGso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SEND))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS))
            .requestScopes(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .build();

    // set up Google client
//        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
//                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
//                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
//                .addApi(Plus.API)
//                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGso)
//                .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    //        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGso)
            .build();

    //mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_REQUIRED); // try to connect right away

    mGmailService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
            .setApplicationName("com.company.appname")
            .build();
```

The silent login is done in the onStart() method of an embedded fragment as:

```
    // try to silently sign in ...
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult =
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
        // There's an immediate result available.
        mSignInAcct = pendingResult.get().getSignInAccount();
        mEmailAcct = mSignInAcct.getEmail();
    } else {
        // There's no immediate result ready, wait for the async callback.
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                mSignInAcct = result.getSignInAccount();
                mEmailAcct = mSignInAcct.getEmail();
            } // if fails, forget it and force a real login later.
        });
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
    boolean b = mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
```

which sometimes connects right away with a valid user account and sometimes not. I do see that b from the ...isConnected() call is false, although isConnected() returns true later in later calls.

Login button code:

```
        gmail_signin_button = (com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gmail_sign_in_button);
        gmail_signin_button.setScopes(mGso.getScopeArray());
        gmail_signin_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
                // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
                mShouldResolve = true;

                // connect if unconnected...
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

                    tv_email_status.setText("G+ connecting");
                    // Show a message to the user that we are signing in.
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Google API connecting ...");
                }
                else {
                    // sign in anew ...
                    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Constants.RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        });
```

onActivityResult code (in part):

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // G+
        if (requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.

            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: code: " + resultCode);
                tv_email_status.setText("Error: code: " + resultCode);
            } else {
                mSignInAcct = result.getSignInAccount();
                mEmailAcct = mSignInAcct.getEmail();
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Gmail signin OK - " + mEmailAcct);
                tv_email_status.setText("Email: " + mEmailAcct);
            }

            mIsResolving = false;
            if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
            }

        } else if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                mEmailAcct = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (mEmailAcct != null) {
                    //mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings = mActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(Constants.PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, mEmailAcct);
                    editor.commit();

                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Gmail: account: " + mEmailAcct);
                    tv_email_status.setText("Gmail: account: " + mEmailAcct);

                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                tv_email_status.setText("Account unspecified.");
            }
        }
        //else if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION) {
            //if (mCredential != null && resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            //    startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), Constants.REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            //}
        //}
```

OK, I will get a good onActivityResult and get valid SignInAcct and EmailAcct values. **It seems that we are logged in fine**, but then the gMail service always fails with a 401 error as explained above.

To do the silent login made me have to add the GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API which then seems to require the GoogleApiClient to connect with SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL which doesn't make sense to me.

I also see that my AccountPicker does nothing now as well. But that is another story/problem, as I said I thought I had this all working until I tried to add that silent feature.

Whew, well I have probably made this harder than it is, can anyone steer me in the right direction? As I said all I want to do is:

1. silently log in if the user has previously done so
2. allow the user to log in or re-log in if needed
3. read the users emails and contacts
4. send email on their behalf.

Comment: OK, I made some progress, the credential must be set the GmailService constructor. So I have code like this

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out, as usual its something simple wrong. The credential in the GmailService constructor must be set, but you don't have this until you try to connect. So I have code like this

```
void setGmailAccess(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    mSignInAcct = result.getSignInAccount();
    mEmailAcct = mSignInAcct.getEmail();

    final Thread task = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                // run in background thread
                String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), "oauth2:profile email");
                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);
                mGmailService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
                        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
                        .setApplicationName("com.company.appname")
                        .build();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore errors
                String error = e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    };

    task.start();

}
```

To set up the GmailService object. It is called from onConnected, where I have code like this in the result success block:

```
    try {

        // try to silently sign in ...
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
            // There's an immediate result available.
            setGmailAccess(pendingResult.get());

        } else {
            // There's no immediate result ready, wait for the async callback.
            pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                    setGmailAccess(result);
                } // if fails, forget it and force a real login later.
            });
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String me = e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

And in the activity result for starting a new login. Seems to work.